# Mono install on windows, mac?

Tags: windows, macos, mono

Is it possible to install Mono and Gtk on a Windows computer, copy that to a local folder, and run from that? Can I do the same on Mac?

I'm trying to create an all-in-one folder with everything included so that users can run without needing anything that is not in the folder. mkbundle did not work, and I'd rather have a complete Mono so I can dynamically load additional Mono libraries at runtime.

Are there any 64-bit vs 32-bit issues?

Can I avoid the GAC by using MONO_PATH?

Do either the Mac Mono or Windows Mono require that any files be in a global place? Any hardcoded paths?

I want my distributed program to be as easy to use as possible for new users (eg, no additional installs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check [Banshee's source code](http://git.gnome.org/browse/banshee) to find out how it's done there.

- For Mac, [bockbuild](https://github.com/mono/bockbuild) is used so all libraries are bundled in the package.
- For Windows, a WiX installer is used. It doesn't bundle Mono because with .NET it's enough. Not sure if this bundles the rest though (gtk#), you should double check.

Comment: Excellent! I haven't tried this yet, but it appears to be exactly what I needed! Thank you so much for the information.