# Ported Win/Mono App to Mac/Mono, now need to build Mac .pkg

Tags: mono, xamarin-studio, monomac, xamarin.mac

I'm an experienced VS coder, but an Xamarin/Mono newbie.

We make electronic equipment that can be configured using a Visual Studio Windows program.  It's just a collection of pulldowns for selecting options, and simple handshaking via RS232 serial port with the target hardware.

Many of our users have asked for a Mac version, so I'm looking at Mono.  Over the past few days I have slowly constructed a new Mono app in Visual Studio, adding one simple feature at a time,  then loading and building it with Xamarin/Mono on a Mac to see that it works.  The results are adequate for what we do.

But it seems that an Xamarin project that is created this way cannot produce a Mac installation package (either .app or .pkg).

On the Mac, I can create a new project/solution in Xamarin using a Mac app template, then the needed options appear in the Build menu to create a .pkg that works exactly as I need.  But I don't want to completely recreate the application using Mac tools.  A working app is being built in VS, and it runs perfectly well with Mono on a Mac.  All I need is an easy way to package it for distribution to our Mac users.

How do I turn my Windows Mono solution into a Mac Mono solution that will build a installer package?

Many thanks,
Jim

Comment: Since VS doesn't support Mac project types I have to ask what is the application targeting as UI framework? Are you using WinForms? Console based?

Comment: your question is probably already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12145204/mono-install-on-windows-mac